# Why does read(2) from Mac OSX pipe(2) insert 0x7F into string?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm opening a pipe to a child process and reading back its standard out through that pipe.

If I just do one read, as I did in my prototype, it correctly returns the string (the BEFORE case below).

If I loop so as to read all possible sized outputs, I get the string plus a terminating 0x7F (ASCII DEL) at the end, which screws up my testing.

This fails only on my laptop running Mac OSX 10.9.4, Clang 3.4.

It works correctly (no 0x7F) on FreeBSD 10.0, Clang 3.3.

Code BEFORE:

```
char buffer[1024];
read(pipeFd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
string output = buffer;
```

Code which FAILS:

```
char buffer[1024];
ssize_t count;
string output;

while ((count = read(pipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) != 0) {
    if (count < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    output.append(buffer);
}
return true;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is this a Mac-related bug?

Comment: Is your *writer* including a terminator (0-char) at the end of the string message being sent to that pipe? Regardless, `output.append(buffer, buffer+count)` should likely be considered.

Comment: The failing code seems to be a function, but `output` is a local variable.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value from `read` -- the number of bytes read!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your string isn't terminated properly.

You can either do `buffer[count] = 0;` (but make sure your buffer has one more element than you are reading, so `read(pipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)` would be required.

Or use the `append` with size:

```
output.append(buffer, count);
```

The 0x7f is probably just some random garbage one position beyond the input - and you are just lucky that it's one character, rather than half a dozen or a megabyte of "extra". [Or that it didn't just read off the end of the memory and crash]

Comment: Sometimes one just can't see the forest for the trees.  :-p  I actually had code which initialized buffer before each read, as well -- so clearly the read() is sticking the 0x7F byte on the end. But this answer (and those like it) are the correct solution:  read() does not guarantee any kind of terminator, and I should be transferring the count number of bytes into my string.  Too obvious, I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, of course.

You are, by appending the entire buffer, instead of the first 'count' bytes of it.

NB your loop condition is wrong, it should be > 0.